# Azure VMSS with application gateway and NAT rules

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer

I have an existing scale set with Application Gateway. I want to add some NAT rules with port forwarding to the scale set instances. So I created a load balancer with inbound NAT rules, and associated it with VMSS. It didn’t throw any error while creation, but now I don’t have any outbound internet connection. Is it possible to create both application gateway and load balancer for a VMSS? If not, is there any other way to create NAT rules?

Comment: how did you create those, can you share the template? neither LB not AppGw block outgoing comms

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding. I figured it out, posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because I had created a standard load balancer which doesn't provide outbound connectivity by default. We are required to add a load balancing rule, or every instance of scale set needs to have its own public ip. From this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#snat